# What is the sequence of actions when my Shocker removes cards and places cards in my opponents hand?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I have a fun little [shocker](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=4848) deck. From Gatherer

> **Whenever Shocker deals damage to a player**, that player discards all the cards in his or her hand, then draws that many cards.

Note that the errata does not specify combat damage. When the stars align I usually have the following auras on the Shocker.

- [Arcane Teachings](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=130530): Enchanted creature gets +2/+2 and has "Tap: This creature deals 1 damage to target creature or player."
- [Sigil of Sleep](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=270813): Whenever enchanted creature deals damage to a player, return target creature that player controls to its owner's hand.

---

My understanding is that when I damage a player (I even targeted myself to get a new hand in desperation) that his hand is discarded and new cards are drawn. Then at the *same time* a creature (assuming there is a legal target) returns to his hand. Netting the player 1 extra card in his hand once the action is completed.

Is this correct? Are there rules addressing this scenario?

Answer (score 7):

When two or more trigger happen at the same time, the player controlling those triggers put them on the stack in an order of his/her choice, beginning with the active player.

So in your scenario, you can put the discard/draw trigger first and the bounce creature trigger second on the stack. This way, the bounce trigger will resolve first, so he/she will have to discard this creature, too, when the other trigger resolves.

Note, that he/she can respond to all triggers placed on the stack. If the bounced creature has Flash for example, he/she could replay it, before he/she has to discard